# Shell Script - save substring to variable

Tags: shell, scripting

A really simple shell script question. I have a file with something like this:

```
var "aaaaa"
var "bbbbb"
...
```

Now, how can I assign the string in quotes to a variable?
This is what I have now (but I'm missing the assign part...):

```
while read line
do
  echo $line | cut -d" " -f3
done
```

which prints what I want... how do I save it to a variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
my_var=$(echo $line | cut -d" " -f3)
```

You need to execute the command. That is what the $() is for.

Comment: In general, you should quote the command substitution and the variable expansion to preserve whitespace: `my_var="$(echo "$line" | cut -d" " -f3)"`. This command is already splitting on the space character, but it may also be important to preserve tabs, newlines, or anything else that might be in IFS.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on a shell.

Bourne and derivatives, you do

`my_var_name=expression`

C shell and derivatives, you do

`setenv my_var_name expression`

If you want to save the output of a command (e.g. "cut xyz"), you use backticks operator as your expression:

```
my_var_name=`echo $line | cut -d" " -f3`
```

I think that bash also supports $() but not sure of a difference from backticks - see section 3.4.5 from http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html

Comment: I'm using bash.
You mean something like: my_var=$line | cut -d" " -f3
? Doesn't seem to work. Prints nothing.
And yes, assigning them to the same variable on each loop would be fine.

Comment: It works on my line on "versionCode = 11" (ignore the double quotes) and it prints 11.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to use external cut command to "cut" you strings. You can use the shell, its more efficient.

```
while read -r a b
do
  echo "Now variable b is your quoted string and has value: $b"
done <"file"
```

Or

```
while read -r line
do
  set -- $line
  echo $2
done <"file"
```